# MySQL/PHP Pagination Issue - Won't go to second page

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Sorry if this is a daft question but I'm still bit of a newbie at this and learning as I go with trial and error.

I have the below Pagination script, it does work however when I click "Next Page" it does not show the last 2 products on the next page. It just stays on the first page with the original 3.

- Total Database Records 5
- Limit set to 3 per page (for testing purposes)

  ```
    <?php
   $dbhost = '*******';
   $dbuser = '*******';
   $dbpass = '*******';

   $rec_limit = 3;
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db('********');

   /* Get total number of records */
   $sql = "SELECT count(id) FROM products ";
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
   $rec_count = $row[0];

   if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) ) {
      $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
      $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
   }else {
      $page = 0;
      $offset = 0;
   }

   $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
   $sql = "SELECT id, name, description, price ". 
      "FROM products ".
      "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
      echo "Product :{$row['name']}  <br> ".
         "Description : {$row['description']} <br> ".
         "Price : {$row['price']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
   }

   if( $page > 0 ) {
      $last = $page - 2;
      echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Previous Page</a> |";
      echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next Page</a>";
   }else if( $page == 0 ) {
      echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $page\">Next Page</a>";
   }else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ) {
      $last = $page - 2;
      echo "<a href = \"$_PHP_SELF?page = $last\">Last Page</a>";
   }

   mysql_close($conn);
  ?>
  ```

Comment: (1) MySQL syntax says: `LIMIT` first and `OFFSET` second. Looking at the variables used in the program, it seems that their positions are interchanged. (2) `$offset` doesn't seem to change when you're at a new page. (3) Once you've got the logic right, please consider switching over to `mysqli_` or `PDO` prepared queries immediately to write scripts that aren't prone to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pagination in php is very simple concepts. You can learn easily. Just follow the below steps.

      1. Find the Start values based on page number:


 $limit=10;
 $page=$_GET['p'];
 if($page=='')
 {
  $page=1;
  $start=0;
 }
 else
 {
  $start=$limit*($page-1);
 }

     Where,
                  $limit is the number rows per page.
                  $page is page number.
                  $start is starting point of limit in mysql query.
If the page number is 1, then the start is 0 which is find by $start=$limit*($page-1).
                  $start=10*(1-1)
                  $start=10*(0)
                  $start=0

If the page number is 2, then the start is 10.
Similarly, if the page number is 3, then the start is 20.

                    2. Find total number of records in mysql table:

Then we need to calculate the total number of data in table. Then find the maximum pages using php script like below:

$tot=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1")  or die(mysql_error());
$total=mysql_num_rows($tot);
$num_page=ceil($total/$limit);


     Where,
                mysql_num_rows() returns the numbers results in numeric.
                ceil() returns the whole digit number. ie, ceil(2.3) => 3.
                $maxpage returns the number of pages.


                     3. Function for pagination:

        The php script for pagination function is:

function pagination($page,$num_page)
{
  echo'<ul ;
  for($i=1;$i<=$num_page;$i++)
  {
     if($i==$page)
{
 echo'<li ;
}
else
{
 echo'<li ;
}
  }
  echo'</ul>';
}      

           Where, 
                        You need to use for loop for display number of pages in mysql table.

Reference: http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/04/php-mysql-pagination.html
```

Comment: This solution can be improved by incorporating limit and offset attributes in the query itself. As of now, it'll fetch all the rows first and then try to find the subset to display. Therefore, it could affect the page loading time tremendously when there's voluminous data in the table. As a general good practice, please try to stay clear of mysql_() functions when proposing a solution, since they're problematic by various standards.